# Initializing a function inside another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

So I basically have a textarea and want to be able to make the font size bigger or smaller with two buttons. I've done it and it works, but to make it work I had to put the content o the function getTextSize inside both the increaseFontSize and decreaseFontSize, and I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

What happens with the code below is that de variable textSize is undefined when I click in either of the buttons.

I know this might be a super-newbie question, the reason being: I'm super-newbie in programming, but I do care about performance and good practices. I could just leave it the way it works but I know there must be some other way.

Thanks.

```
<body>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<div class="fontSizeButtons">
    <button id="biggerFontBtn">Bigger Font</button>
    <button id="smallerFontBtn">Smaller Font</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var biggerFont = document.getElementById('biggerFontBtn');
var smallerFont = document.getElementById('smallerFontBtn');

biggerFont.addEventListener('click', increaseFontSize, false);
smallerFont.addEventListener('click', decreaseFontSize, false);

function getTextSize() {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(editor, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var textSize = parseFloat(style);
}

function increaseFontSize() {
    getTextSize();
    editor.style.fontSize = (textSize + 3) + 'px';
}

function decreaseFontSize() {
    getTextSize();
    editor.style.fontSize = (textSize - 3) + 'px';
}

</script>
```

Comment: you may want to have a look through the answers and select the best one for you and up/downvote the ones you like/dislike... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the variables `style` and `textSize` at the beginning, outside of the function, and it will work.

```js
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var biggerFont = document.getElementById('biggerFontBtn');
var smallerFont = document.getElementById('smallerFontBtn');
var style;
var textSize;

biggerFont.addEventListener('click', increaseFontSize, false);
smallerFont.addEventListener('click', decreaseFontSize, false);

function getTextSize() {
    style = window.getComputedStyle(editor, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    textSize = parseFloat(style);
}

function increaseFontSize() {
    getTextSize();
    editor.style.fontSize = (textSize + 3) + 'px';
}

function decreaseFontSize() {
    getTextSize();
    editor.style.fontSize = (textSize - 3) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<div class="fontSizeButtons">
    <button id="biggerFontBtn">Bigger Font</button>
    <button id="smallerFontBtn">Smaller Font</button>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/gh03a7ue/

Answer (score 0):

Including the same function twice isn't the best of practices. However you could do this;

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor'),
    biggerFont = document.getElementById('biggerFontBtn')
    smallerFont = document.getElementById('smallerFontBtn');
biggerFont.addEventListener('click', increaseFontSize, false);
smallerFont.addEventListener('click', decreaseFontSize, false);
function getTextSize() {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(editor, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  return parseFloat(style);
}
function increaseFontSize() {
  editor.style.fontSize = (getTextSize() + 3) + 'px';
}
function decreaseFontSize() {
  editor.style.fontSize = (getTextSize() - 3) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: you're including the function twice too :)

Comment: I'm using it twice, I'm not making the function twice, once in each of the `FontSize` functions